# Kaspersky detects Java.exe as a virus, is this a fault?

Tags: java, malware, trojan, kaspersky

[image]

Kaspersky detected Java.exe as a virus (Apparently Trojan.Win32.Generic)

Is this a fault or is this seriously a virus?

Comment: [This thread](https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?p=315241) seems to indicate a false positive.

Comment: Do you trust the executable in that directory?  If you do then ignore the virus detection, because you trust it, so its not a virus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some Googling for you and it looks like Kaspersky seems to have a long standing problem with Java so it's possible it's a false positive.

Ultimately though it comes down to if you trust the source of the package, did you verify the package before installing?

Another way to be sure is to perhaps submit `java.exe` in `C:\programs files\android\android-studio\jre\bin\` to virustotal.com